# Why are screen readers not reading out the label for a select element

Tags: html, accessibility

If I have a standard select element with a label, like this:

```
<label for="mySelect">My Select</label>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Please select</option>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
</select>
```

When I am using JAWS or mac voiceover, the screen reader reads the first option and not the label.

Is there some aria-attribute I should be adding to get the screen reader to read the label?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is unfortunately the expected behavior with Jaws according to [Testing Select box labels with Screen Readers](http://www.davidmacd.com/blog/select-box-label.html) when using the Virtual Cursor.

The user has to use the `tab` key to get the associated label